# Redux ListView doesn't rerender content after action dispatch

Tags: listview, react-native, redux, thunk

I'm using redux almost exactly like the async reddit redux example, using thunk middleware to only update the state if needed (shouldFetch). Has anyone noticed that a React-Native ListView doesn't catch the change after a network call updates the store? If I navigate away and back it appears fine. It's just after a network call (from the previous route) that it doesn't appear.

My ListView.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
    sectionHeaderHasChanged: this.sectionHeaderHasChanged,
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  });

  this.state = {
    dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.books),
  }

  this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  this.selectBook = this.selectBook.bind(this);
}

selectBook(book) {
  this.props.selectBook(book)
}

goTo(route) {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: route,
  });
}
... + everything you'd expect
```

Comment: It seems like [this](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/683) is on the right track

Answer (score 0):

The major understanding here is that the listview elements like flatlist and sectionlist are pureComponent, meaning they won't re-render when the props change. So, to overcome this we need to pass an extra field to the listview component namely "extraData". Please refer this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) for detailed doc.

**Bonus point**
https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#listview-initial-rendering-is-too-slow-or-scroll-performance-is-bad-for-large-lists